Использование var в джаве
Что не так с выведением типов var в джаве? Коллега спросил, для чего я часто использую var, и не отголоски ли это джаваскрипта с динамической типизацией.
А у меня это отголоски выведения типов auto в C++. Стоит ли на проектах с джавой использовать var вместо явного указания типов? В чем плюсы и минусы? Вы используете var?

Всё, что делает var - экономит немного буковок в коде, никакой динамической типизации тут не появляется

Не путай Java и JavaScript - это разные вещи. "Java (не путать с JavaScript) — строго типизированный объектно-ориентированный язык программирования."

В целом да, это больше похоже на auto в С++, и аналог того же var в C#, появившегося в версии 3.0 в 2007 году на 10+ лет раньше, чем в Java 10, вышедшей в марте 2018 года.

Плюсы: не надо писать явно тип переменной и перегружать этим код. Минусы: 1. Автоматический вывод типа может быть не всегда нужный, типичный пример var list = new ArrayList() ≠ List list = new ArrayList(); 2. Может затруднить беглое чтение кода, к примеру встретится var userData = userService.getData() и без дополнительных телодвижений можно только гадать будет там еще тип, список, массив, map или что-то еще. Поэтому большинство предпочитает использовать var как правило для локальных переменных и ограниченно.

Компилятор выводит тип  на основе значения, которое присваивают переменной. Но этим не стоит злоупотреблять.
Случаи, в которых, можно уместно использовать var:

Можно легко определить тип переменной, посмотрев, на присваиваемое значение:
var stream = url.getInputStream();
var name = person.getFullName();


Тип переменной не важен для понимания кода:
for(var tmp : list) 
  System.out.println(tmp);




Чтобы понять var, предлагаю вспомнить что-нибудь похожее — например, вывод типа (англ. type inference), который появился в 7 Jav'е:
SomeGenericClass<Integer> = new SomeGenericClass<>();

Это же никакая не динамическая типизация, верно? Тип во вторых угловых скобках очевиден. И поэтому его не надо указывать дважды.
При создании объектов тип пишется тоже два раза. И если название класса длинное, то это может быть неудобно:
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField();

Поэтому первое объявление типа можно заменить на var (если это локальная переменная, конечно!). И получится кратко и понятно:
var textField = new JFormattedTextField();

Компилятор прекрасно поймёт, что должно быть вместо var.
Но тут главное не переусердствовать с новинкой и не понаписать непонятных var'ов. Антипример:
//comboBox = javax.swing.JComboBox
var item = comboBox.getItemAt(3);

В качестве item'а может быть вообще что угодно, класс JComboBox параметризованный, а метод getItemAt() возвращает E. Придётся смотреть, как этот объект был объявлен, с каким типом данных он работает...
